# JQuery To check all checkboxes in td based on classname of tr in horizontal

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

[image]here is my sample code. Attached an image. the format which is required to me

```js
$("table tbody").on("change", "input[type=checkbox]", function (e) { 
    var currentCB = $(this);
    var isChecked = this.checked;
    if (currentCB.is(".groupHeadCheck")) {
        var allCbs = currentCB.closest('tr').nextUntil('tr.groupHead').find('[type="checkbox"]').prop('checked', isChecked);
    } else {
        var allCbs = currentCB.closest('tr').prevAll("tr.groupHead:first").nextUntil('tr.groupHead').andSelf().find('[type="checkbox"]');
        var allSlaves = allCbs.not(".groupHeadCheck");
        var master = allCbs.filter(".groupHeadCheck");
        var allChecked;
        if (!isChecked) {
            allChecked = false;
        } else {
            allChecked = allSlaves.filter(":checked").length === allSlaves.length;
        }
        master.prop("checked", allChecked);
    }
});

$(".groupHead").next().find("[type=checkbox]").change();
```

```css
.groupHead td { background-color: #CCC; }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <th>
                1. <input type="checkbox" class="groupHeadCheck" />
            </th>
            <td>
                <input type="checkbox" id="1" />
            </td>
            <td>
                <input type="checkbox" id="2" />
            </td>
            <td>
                <input type="checkbox" id="3" />
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th>
                2. <input type="checkbox" class="groupHeadCheck" />
            </th>
            <td>
                <input type="checkbox" id="4" />
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th>
               3.  <input type="checkbox" class="groupHeadCheck" />
            </th>
            <td>
                <input type="checkbox" id="6" checked="checked" />
            </td>
            <td>
                <input type="checkbox" id="7" checked="checked"/>
            </td>
        </tr>        
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Here the code in [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/praveen04/3ybuve18/3/)  is working fine for vertical.

1. When the checkbox in the first row with class groupHeadCheck, all the checkboxes of id 1, 2 and 3 will also be checked.
2. And if all the checkboxes of 1, 2, and 3 are already checked, the checkbox in first row will be checked.
3. I want to get this worked in a horizontal pattern rather in vertical

Please, any help!

Comment: your 1 and 2 seems to be fine for me, if you want your checkboxes horizontal you can add float: left to trs

Comment: @ChrisLi if you see when I am checking 1. `tr` 2 and 3 `tr` is being checked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Also You can use this to check master's checkboxes in the beginning

```js
$("table tbody")
  .each((index, tbody) => {
    $(tbody).find('tr').each((index, tr) => checkMasterCheckboxesInTr(tr))
  })
  .on("change", "input[type=checkbox]", function (e) { 
      var currentCB = $(this);
      var isChecked = this.checked;

      if (currentCB.is(".groupHeadCheck")) {
          var allCbs = currentCB.closest('tr').find('[type="checkbox"]').prop('checked', isChecked);
      } else {
          checkMasterCheckboxesInTr(currentCB.closest('tr'))
      }
  });

function checkMasterCheckboxesInTr(tr) {
  var allCbs = $(tr).find('[type="checkbox"]');
  var allSlaves = allCbs.not(".groupHeadCheck");
  var master = allCbs.filter(".groupHeadCheck");
  var allChecked = allSlaves.filter(":checked").length === allSlaves.length;
  master.prop("checked", allChecked);
}
```

```css
.groupHead td { background-color: #CCC; }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <th>
                1. <input type="checkbox" class="groupHeadCheck" />
            </th>
            <td>
                <input type="checkbox" id="1" />
            </td>
            <td>
                <input type="checkbox" id="2" />
            </td>
            <td>
                <input type="checkbox" id="3" />
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th>
                2. <input type="checkbox" class="groupHeadCheck" />
            </th>
            <td>
                <input type="checkbox" id="4" />
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th>
               3.  <input type="checkbox" class="groupHeadCheck" />
            </th>
            <td>
                <input type="checkbox" id="6" checked="checked" />
            </td>
            <td>
                <input type="checkbox" id="7" checked="checked"/>
            </td>
        </tr>        
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1):

Just simplify few strings of code

```js
$("table tbody").on("change", "input[type=checkbox]", function (e) { 
    var currentCB = $(this);
    var isChecked = this.checked;
    
    if (currentCB.is(".groupHeadCheck")) {
        var allCbs = currentCB.closest('tr').find('[type="checkbox"]').prop('checked', isChecked);
    } else {
        var allCbs = currentCB.closest('tr').find('[type="checkbox"]');
        var allSlaves = allCbs.not(".groupHeadCheck");
        var master = allCbs.filter(".groupHeadCheck");
        var allChecked;
        if (!isChecked) {
            allChecked = false;
        } else {
            allChecked = allSlaves.filter(":checked").length === allSlaves.length;
        }
        master.prop("checked", allChecked);
    }
});

$(".groupHead").next().find("[type=checkbox]").change();
```

```css
.groupHead td { background-color: #CCC; }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <th>
                1. <input type="checkbox" class="groupHeadCheck" />
            </th>
            <td>
                <input type="checkbox" id="1" />
            </td>
            <td>
                <input type="checkbox" id="2" />
            </td>
            <td>
                <input type="checkbox" id="3" />
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th>
                2. <input type="checkbox" class="groupHeadCheck" />
            </th>
            <td>
                <input type="checkbox" id="4" />
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th>
               3.  <input type="checkbox" class="groupHeadCheck" />
            </th>
            <td>
                <input type="checkbox" id="6" checked="checked" />
            </td>
            <td>
                <input type="checkbox" id="7" checked="checked"/>
            </td>
        </tr>        
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1):

Check this

```js
$("table tbody").on("change", "input[type=checkbox]", function (e) { 
    var currentCB = $(this);
    var pt =  $(this).parents("tr");
    var isChecked = this.checked;
    pt.find("input[type=checkbox]").prop("checked", isChecked);
   
});

$(".groupHead").next().find("[type=checkbox]").change();
```

```css
.groupHead td { background-color: #CCC; }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <th>
                1. <input type="checkbox" class="groupHeadCheck" />
            </th>
            <td>
                <input type="checkbox" id="1" />
            </td>
            <td>
                <input type="checkbox" id="2" />
            </td>
            <td>
                <input type="checkbox" id="3" />
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th>
                2. <input type="checkbox" class="groupHeadCheck" />
            </th>
            <td>
                <input type="checkbox" id="4" />
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th>
               3.  <input type="checkbox" class="groupHeadCheck" />
            </th>
            <td>
                <input type="checkbox" id="6" checked="checked" />
            </td>
            <td>
                <input type="checkbox" id="7" checked="checked"/>
            </td>
        </tr>        
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Slightly modified your code I hope you are looking for this logic.. please comment if it works

```js
$("table tbody").on("change", ".groupHeadCheck", function (e) { 
    var currentCB = $(this);
    var pt =  $(this).parents("tr");
    var isChecked = this.checked;
    pt.find("input[type=checkbox]").prop("checked", isChecked);
   
});

$(".groupHead").next().find("[type=checkbox]").change();
```

```css
.groupHead td { background-color: #CCC; }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <th>
                1. <input type="checkbox" class="groupHeadCheck" />
            </th>
            <td>
                <input type="checkbox" id="1" />
            </td>
            <td>
                <input type="checkbox" id="2" />
            </td>
            <td>
                <input type="checkbox" id="3" />
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th>
                2. <input type="checkbox" class="groupHeadCheck" />
            </th>
            <td>
                <input type="checkbox" id="4" />
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th>
               3.  <input type="checkbox" class="groupHeadCheck" />
            </th>
            <td>
                <input type="checkbox" id="6" checked="checked" />
            </td>
            <td>
                <input type="checkbox" id="7" checked="checked"/>
            </td>
        </tr>        
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: it is working good, but still need modification if we select each box individually and all selected then select all checkbox should also be checked. you can @Александр Чертков is done as per requirement. anyhow thanks for the help.

Comment: @PullataPraveen you mean if we check any checkbox in row you need to check all right?

Answer (score 1):

I have done what you want.

It will also automatically check checkbox on page load if all other checkbox checked then it will check the first checkbox.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Test</title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
</head>
<body>

    <table>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <th>
                    1. <input type="checkbox" class="groupHeadCheck" />
                </th>
                <td>
                    <input type="checkbox" id="1" />
                </td>
                <td>
                    <input type="checkbox" id="2" />
                </td>
                <td>
                    <input type="checkbox" id="3" />
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <th>
                    2. <input type="checkbox" class="groupHeadCheck" />
                </th>
                <td>
                    <input type="checkbox" id="4" />
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <th>
                   3.  <input type="checkbox" class="groupHeadCheck" />
                </th>
                <td>
                    <input type="checkbox" id="6" checked="checked" />
                </td>
                <td>
                    <input type="checkbox" id="7" checked="checked"/>
                </td>
            </tr>        
        </tbody>
    </table>



    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>
    $(document).on("change", "input[type=checkbox]", function (e) { 
        var currentCB = $(this);
        var isChecked = this.checked;
        if (currentCB.is(".groupHeadCheck")) {
             currentCB.parents('tr').find('[type="checkbox"]').prop('checked', isChecked);
        } 

        $(document).find('tr').each(function(){
           var total_chk_in_row = jQuery(this).find('[type="checkbox"]').length;
           var total_checked_chk = jQuery(this).find('td > [type="checkbox"]:checked').length;

           if((total_chk_in_row - 1) == total_checked_chk){
                jQuery(this).find('.groupHeadCheck').prop('checked',true);
           }

        });
    });

     $(document).find('tr').each(function(){
           var total_chk_in_row = jQuery(this).find('[type="checkbox"]').length;
           var total_checked_chk = jQuery(this).find('td > [type="checkbox"]:checked').length;

           if((total_chk_in_row - 1) == total_checked_chk){
                jQuery(this).find('.groupHeadCheck').prop('checked',true);
           }

     });

    $(".groupHead").next().find("[type=checkbox]").change();
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try the following way:

```js
$("table tbody").on("change", "input[type=checkbox]", function (e) { 
    if($(this).hasClass('groupHeadCheck') && $(this).is(':checked')){
      $(this).closest('tr').find('td input').prop('checked', 'checked');
    }
    else if($(this).hasClass('groupHeadCheck') && $(this).not(':checked')){
      $(this).closest('tr').find('td input').removeAttr('checked');
    }
    
    if(!$(this).hasClass('groupHeadCheck')){
      var total = $(this).closest('tr').find('td input').length;
      var chekced = $(this).closest('tr').find('td input:checked').length;
      if(total == chekced){
        $(this).closest('tr').find('th .groupHeadCheck').prop('checked', 'checked');
      }
      else{
        $(this).closest('tr').find('th .groupHeadCheck').removeAttr('checked');
      }
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <th>
                1. <input type="checkbox" class="groupHeadCheck" />
            </th>
            <td>
                <input type="checkbox" id="1" />
            </td>
            <td>
                <input type="checkbox" id="2" />
            </td>
            <td>
                <input type="checkbox" id="3" />
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th>
                2. <input type="checkbox" class="groupHeadCheck" />
            </th>
            <td>
                <input type="checkbox" id="4" />
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th>
               3.  <input type="checkbox" class="groupHeadCheck" />
            </th>
            <td>
                <input type="checkbox" id="6" checked="checked" />
            </td>
            <td>
                <input type="checkbox" id="7" checked="checked"/>
            </td>
        </tr>        
    </tbody>
</table>
```